# Get Changed Lines With TFS API

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

I'm already getting the changesets of given file. I want know the details of each changeset.
More specifically, I want see what lines was changed. Is there any way to achieve that?

Below my code to get changesets:

```
    public IEnumerable<Changeset> GetChangeSets(string serverItem)
    {
        return (IEnumerable<Changeset>)
            VersionControlServer.QueryHistory(
            path: serverItem,
            version: VersionSpec.Latest,
            deletionId: 0,
            recursion: RecursionType.None,
            user: null,
            versionFrom: new ChangesetVersionSpec(1),
            versionTo: VersionSpec.Latest,
            maxCount: int.MaxValue,
            includeChanges: true,
            slotMode: false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that information isn't available via the API. As far as I know, that data isn't stored in TFS at all... When you run a file comparison, it compares the old and new versions of the file using a standard diff tool.

Comment: So when you open one diff in any of your changesets, tfs compare in real time the changes?

Comment: Someone from Microsoft would have to provider commentary on that aspect.